# Return an array containing the squared errors between all predicted_prices and the actual prices (from the dataset)

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I'm doing an exercise and I'm stuck.

Here's what I have to do:

I've been given a function to implement which has 4 arguments.

`def squared_errors(slope, intercept, surfaces, prices`

And I tried with a friend to get that function to work but none of us found the solution.

Basically, I have been given a dataset and I have to make sure that our estimator line is the best possible one, we need to compute the Mean Squared Error between price and
predicted_price (slope * surface + intercept). The dataset is a vector of shape(1000,1).

for each row, we should evaluate the squared_error (predicted_price - price)**2

But my brain is just numb and I can't come to a solution, and help would be greatly appreciate. !

Answer (score 0):

Given the `slope` and the `intercept`, for any given data point `x` you can get its prediction as `slope*x+intercept` (or generally as `slope^T.X+intrecept` when it is vetorized)

Now that we have the predictions, if we have the actual ground truth then we can measure how good/bad our predictions are using squared loss which is nothing but just the square root of the mean of the squared difference between the prediction and the corresponding actual ground truth.

#### Sample (documented inline)

```
import numpy as np

# Actual slope 
slope = 2 
# Actual intercept
intercept = 0

# Some data
X = np.random.rand(10,1)
# The ground truth 
prices = slope*X + intercept

# Loss
def squared_errors(slope, intercept, surfaces, prices):
    y_hat = slope*surfaces + intercept
    return np.sqrt(np.mean((y_hat - prices)**2))
    
# prefect prediction    
print (squared_errors(2, 0, X, prices))
# Non prefect prediction    
print (squared_errors(2, 0.5, X, prices))
print (squared_errors(1, 0, X, prices))
```

Output:

```
0.0
0.5
0.6286343914881158
```

As you can see for the prefect prediction the error is 0 and non zero for the rest based on how far way on average the predictions are from the ground truth.